# How should I write Jest Test cases for styled component and spy on css to verify if the styles?

Tags: css, reactjs, jestjs, styled-components

I have a component in React-redux, which has a PagedGrid component (basically a table which renders data row-wise).

```js
<UsersContainer>
  <Title>{t('users')}</Title>
  <PagedGrid
    data-auto-container="user:table"
    pageData={user.data}
    columns={this.column}
  />
</UsersContainer>
```

I have created a function for the custom styled component which applies css to the rows of the table inside PagedGrid

```js
const UsersContainer = styled.div`
  > table > tbody {
    ${props => customcss(props)};
  }
`;
```

```js
function customcss({ data = [] }) {
  let styles = '';
  if (data.length > 0) {
    data.forEach((value, index) => {
      if (value.mycondition) {
        const rowStyle = `& > tr:nth-child(${index + 1}) {
          background-color: ${LIGHT_BLUE}
        }`;
      }
    });
  }
  return css` ${rowStyle} `;
}
```

Now I want to create a test case using jest to spy on the css of this table and check if the styles are getting applied or not. Can anyone help me on creating a test case for this.

Comment: Maybe [getComputedStyle](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle).

Comment: @DrewReese Do you have some examples, or any blog link which i can refer, i could not find any particular sample code to write my test cases

Comment: This sort of depends on the test rendering framework (enzyme, react-testing-library, etc...) being used, i.e. what the component under test is being rendered into, but the gist is you query *that* html element/wrapper for the tested element and get the computed styled object and simply make assertions on the values. I don't have any specific example nor do I know of any blogs/tutorials. TBH it would probably be easier to just unit test *your* `customcss` function in isolation (this is what unit testing *actually* is anyway). What you're trying to do is to test 3rd-party code.

Comment: BTW, you appear to have a bug in your `customcss` function. If `value.myCondition` is *never* truthy then `rowStyle` isn't declared. Perhaps you meant to update and return `styles`.

Comment: Thank you @DrewReese I found that bug while working on it yesterday, i will try to set the code for test, and value asstertion, one way i am thinking is to first get the wrapper of the component using shallow and then get the nested PagedGrid or UserContainer, and then find out the styling is.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you use the `@testing-library/react` library, you could test your component's style by getting it directly from the html document, and see precisely what style is used for your specific element.

In your example, you can do something like below (assuming that the `${LIGHT_BLUE}` value is `blue`):

```js
import React from 'react';
import { render } from '@testing-library/react';
import UsersContainer from '../UsersContainer';

it('should have the background color set to blue', () => {
  const { container, getAllByTestId } = render(
    <UsersContainer />
  );

  // Replace <YOUR_CSS_SELECTOR> by your component's css selector (that can be found in the inspector panel)
  let contentDiv = document.querySelector('<YOUR_CSS_SELECTOR>');
  let style = window.getComputedStyle(contentDiv[0]);
  expect(style.color).toBe('blue');
}
```

Here, to get the style of your element, I am using the element's `CSS Selector`. However, it could also work with the element's `className`, or `id` directly if it has one, respectively using the methods `document.getElementByClassName('YOUR_DIV_CLASS_NAME')`, `document.getElementId('YOUR_DIV_ID')` instead of document.querySelector('<YOUR_CSS_SELECTOR>'). Note that the given name here should be unique, either with the `id` technique, or the `className`.